# How to invoke a service on pinch to zoom in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm wandering that is it possible to invoke a service on pinch to zoom in/out in android, please don't mind if this is a silly doubt for you, please help me in understanding.

```
startService(MyService);
```

How to invoke this service on pinch to zoom in on top of any activity.

To detect `pinch to zoom` I'm using the following code in my `MainActivity`

```
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
final int action = ev.getAction();
switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();

    mLastTouchX = x;
    mLastTouchY = y;

    // Save the ID of this pointer
    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
    // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
    final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
    final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
    final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

    mPosX += dx;
    mPosY += dy;

    mLastTouchX = x;
    mLastTouchY = y;

    invalidate();
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
    // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
    final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
            >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
    if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
        // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
        // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
        final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
        mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
    }
    break;
}
}

return true;
}
```

Knowledge sharing would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you take a look to gesture in android?

Comment: What's the problem, detecting the pinch or connecting to the service?

Comment: @Jebik take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/index.html its been explained in the following link in the official website, but I'm getting what I really need to build my application.

Comment: @m0skit0 `detecting pinch` has been explained in official site only, but they are using to `pinch an image` I want just to pinch and detect the pinch to execute my desired task.

Comment: Detect pinch where? Anywhere in the Activity? Only in a desired region? Try to detail what you want instead of having us asking and guessing.

Comment: @m0skit0 please refer the edited post, Thanks.